# How use an if statement to change the output message

Tags: ls, output

When i run this command it still outputs the same message when nothing is in the waste bin directory, how could I get the command to output a different message when there are no files in the bin?

```
            #! /bin/bash
            #! listwaste - Lists the names of all the files in your waste bin and their size
            #! Daniel Foster 23-11-2015

            echo "The files that are in the waste bin are:"

            ls -1 ~/bin/.waste/
```

I know this should be simple but I'm just starting out and I am guessing i should be using an if statement or something similar.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oneliner:**

```
trash() { ls -1 ~/bin/.waste; }; [[ $(trash | wc -l) -eq 0 ]] && echo no waste || echo -e "waste:\n$(trash)"
```

**Better formatted:**

```
trash() { ls -1 ~/bin/.waste; }
[[ $(trash | wc -l) -eq 0 ]] && echo no waste || echo -e "waste:\n$(trash)"
```

**Nerd formatted:**

```
#!/bin/bash

function trash() {
  ls -1 ~/bin/.waste
}

if [[ $(trash | wc -l) -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo 'There are no files in the waste bin.'
else
  echo 'The files that are in the waste bin are:'
  trash
fi
```

All 3 examples are performing the exact same functionality, only formatted differently, depending on preference.

If you want to actually be able to run the command `listwaste`, then put this in a script named `listwaste`, make sure you make it executable (`chmod +x`), and save the script in a directory that is listed in your `$PATH`.  You can `echo $PATH` to see these directories that contain executables that you will be able to call directly from the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the output to a variable, behave different-like, depending:

```
$ mkdir ~/bin/.waste
$ OUTPUT=$( ls -1 ~/bin/.waste )
$ if [[ -z "$OUTPUT" ]]; then echo no waste; else echo $OUTPUT; fi
no waste
$ touch ~/bin/.waste/blkasdjf
$ OUTPUT=$( ls -1 ~/bin/.waste )
$ if [[ -z "$OUTPUT" ]]; then echo no waste; else echo $OUTPUT; fi
blkasdjf
$
```

Comment: You don't have to put spaces in between your command variable parentheses, and you don't have to quote variables when they are in double-brackets.  You should also double-quote the `OUTPUT=` variable command (`"$(ls -1 ~/bin/.waste)"`) so that spacing is preserved accurately.  Also, it's not a good practice to create Bash variables in all caps. Ideally, it should read `output="$(ls -1 ~/bin/.waste)"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
file_count=$(ls -1 ~/bin/.waste | wc -l)
if [[ $file_count == 0 ]]; then
    echo "There are no files in the waste bin"
else
    echo "The files that are in the waste bin are:"
    ls -1 ~/bin/.waste
fi
```